# Install conda package to base python env

Tags: python, pip, conda, databricks, ipopt

I'm using `databricks` for `Spark` and one of the packages I want to install is `cyipopt` for Python. `cyipopt` [documentation](https://cyipopt.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html) recommends installation of the package from `conda-forge` using the command

```
conda install -c conda-forge cyipopt
```

The problem is, `databricks` has recently disabled `conda` due to the some terms and conditions update of Anaconda, and only supports `pip` where `cyipopt` isn't available. So, I'm looking for alternate methods of installing this package with no luck so far. One of the things I tried is to install `conda` in `databricks` using:

```
%sh mkdir -p ./miniconda3

%sh wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-latest-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ./miniconda3/miniconda.sh

%sh bash ./miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p ./miniconda3

%sh ./miniconda3/bin/conda install -c conda-forge cyipopt
```

The above commands installed `conda` successfully, but the last command to install `cyipopt` kept running for multiple hours when I tried it many many times, so I just assumed it failed.

Secondly, I manually downloaded all the tar.bz2 files of `cyipopt` from `conda-forge` and its dependencies and was able to manually install all of them successfully including `cyipopt`, but looks like they are not accessible by the default Python of `databricks` (likely because `conda` installed them in a different env).

Can I get `conda` to install packages in the same env as the default Python instead of in its own new environment? Or is there any other easier way to install `cyipopt` package in the default environment?

Comment: Maybe have a look at how people install Conda on Colab, since that's a similar situation where they are trying to sideload packages into a default Python. Also, if the plan is to use Conda Forge, switch to [a Miniforge variant](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) instead of Miniconda. Personally, I prefer Mambaforge.

Comment: Thanks @merv, I found an article based on your comment which helped me understand how to make `conda` libraries available to default Python. towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522

Answer (score 0):

I got a solution from this article which talks about a similar process for Colab, https://towardsdatascience.com/conda-google-colab-75f7c867a522

Note that `%sh` in the below code is the magic command of `databricks` that is used to run shell commands.

```
## install conda
%sh mkdir -p ./miniconda3

# ## download miniconda compatible with below python
# ## from https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html
import sys
print(sys.version)

## change Miniconda download link relevant to your python version, the below link is for Python 3.8 only
%sh wget https://repo.anaconda.com/miniconda/Miniconda3-py38_4.12.0-Linux-x86_64.sh -O ./miniconda3/miniconda.sh

%sh bash ./miniconda3/miniconda.sh -b -u -p /usr/local

%sh which conda

%sh rm -rf ./miniconda3/miniconda.sh

%sh conda init bash
%sh conda init zsh

%sh conda --version

## update conda 
## change python version below to your python version
%sh conda install --channel defaults conda python=3.8 --yes
%sh conda update --channel defaults --all --yes

%sh conda --version

## add conda packages path to sys.path so that Python can find those packages
import sys
sys.path

## change python version to your respective python version
_ = (sys.path.append("/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages"))

## install your package
%sh conda install -c conda-forge cyipopt --yes

import cyipopt
```